# counterexample of semi-continuous fibre dimension on target scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose both $X$ and $Y$ are integral schemes of finite type overk $k$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a surjective finite type  $k$-morphism, where $k$ is a field.

We know $\{x\in X\ | \ \mathrm{dim}_{x}(X_{f(x)}) \geq n \}$ is a closed subset of $X$ for any $n\geq 0$. It is an exercise(II, ex 3.22) of Hartshorne. We also know that $\{y\in Y\ | \ \mathrm{dim}(X_{y}) \geq n \}$ is closed subset of $Y$ for any $n\geq 0$ when $f$ is proper. It is the famous Chevalley's theorem.  But I want to know why $f$ should be proper？ In other word, I want to find a surjective $f$ where semicontinuos theorem is not held on $Y$.

If we don't require $f$ to be surjective , then $f:\mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ so that $f(x,y)=(xy,y)$ is a counterexample, where $f$ is dominant map. But I don't know how to give a counterxample if we require $f$ to be surjective morphism.

Comment: Maybe you try restricted class of schemes. Schafarevich's "Basic algebraic geometry I" on p.76 states that $\{y\in Y\ | \ \mathrm{dim}(f^{-1}(y)) \geq n \}$ are closed subsets of $Y$ if $f: X \to Y$ is a regular surjective map between irreducible quasi-projective varieties (over algebraically closed field).

"Topologically speaking" one needs proper morphism so that image of closed set is closed :)